# Bomberman Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make bomberman using vanilla JS, for my examination project.

I am a little stuck right now with how to take out the bombs in the array and push them into the array again after they explode.

They need to explode after 2 seconds.

My code for bombs:

```
function bombPlayerOne() {
    let ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet(game.q.getResult('bomb'))
    let temp = new createjs.Sprite(ss, "bombIt");
    temp.x = playerOne.x;
    temp.y = playerOne.y;
    game.stage.addChild(temp);
    powerUps.bombs.push(temp);
    console.log("player one placed a bomb");
    for (var i = powerUps.bombs.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        powerUps.bombs.splice;

        // TODO : tween bomber ud...

        powerUps.bombs.push;
    }
}

function bombPlayerTwo() {
    let ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet(game.q.getResult('bomb'))
    let temp = new createjs.Sprite(ss, "bombIt");
    temp.x = playerTwo.x;
    temp.y = playerTwo.y;
    game.stage.addChild(temp);
    powerUps.bombs.push(temp);
    console.log("player two placed a bomb");
    for (var i = powerUps.bombs.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        powerUps.bombs.splice;

        // TODO : tween bomber ud...

        powerUps.bombs.push;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for, are you asking: when bombs explode how would you return a placeable bomb to the player?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i need to do.. but i aint sure how to do it @EricH

Comment: Could you perhaps show some code where `powerUps.bombs` is defined as well as `game.stage`?

Comment: Hey @ThomasHermansen, did you ever get this working?

Comment: yes i made it, but was difficult.

Comment: and thanks a lot @Eric H

Comment: @ThomasHermansen, cool! Share a link if you can, I'd love to see it. Also, if what I answered was helpful, please accept it as the answer - helps my SO rating.

Comment: Hi @EricH lamyai.dk/bomberman still some flaws in the game but it is working now, how do i accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a few options, and FYI this isn't necessarily a javascript question so much as how do you handle game logic/code design type of question.

1) A bomb when placed contains a reference back to it's owner. ie

```
bomb.owner = playerOne
```

2) You have a manager that controls the state of a level, which keeps track of bombs

```
LevelManager.player1Bombs = ....
```

3) You have an array of bombs placed belonging to each player, which you then update during your logic update calls.

```
  function gameUpdate(long milliSecondsSinceLastFrame){
    for(bomb in playerOne.placedBombs){
      if(bomb.isExploded){
        //do other cleanup
        playerOne.availableBombs ++;
      }
    }
    //... do same for player 2 etc
  }
```

All of them have their own advantages/disadvantages.